# Capture ALL CAPS "phrase" in text

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to extract from a long text a sequence of several words all in caps. So, in the example:

> Here is a couple words of text.  If you want more information please reference the DOCUMENT RECORDS log.  It explains the PATH TO ENLIGHTENMENT book that will solve all problems.  Also, don't forget the CAR TUNE-UP GUIDELINES.

I want to capture `DOCUMENT RECORDS`, `PATH TO ENLIGHTENMENT` and `CAR TUNE-UP GUIDELINES`.

The following regex's appear to work in Rubular (except that they don't match cases with hyphens are included).

```
(\b([A-Z]|-|\s){3,}\b)    
(\b[A-Z- ]{3,}\b)
(\b[A-Z-\s]{3,}\b)
```

However, I can't get them to work in my program. When I run the following code in my program (it is a rake task),

```
if content.to_s.scan(/\b[A-Z-\s]{3,}\b/)
  item_title = content.to_s.scan(/\b[A-Z-\s]{3,}\b/)
```

I get the following error:

```
... Long stack trace followed by:

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```

If I replace the `\s` with just a space, I don't receive an error but it no longer seems to match anything. I am running Ruby 1.9.3. Why does it work on the rubular.com site but not in my program? I realize that my regex is sloppy. How can I improve it to be more precise?

Comment: What exact version of ruby 1.9.3 do you use, p0 or p125 or other? Possibly you really encountered a bug in the Ruby and you should report it. With 1.9.3-p0 this regex works as expected (by the way, you should escape `-` symbol in your regex as far as it is a special character: `/\b[A-Z\-\s]{3,}\b/`).

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Escaping the hyphen - as you suggested - seems to have resolved the issue of crashing the program.  I am running 1.9.3-p0.  Unfortunately, it does not resolve the issue of getting the Regex to work.  It doesn't return the three items that I am looking for.  Any suggestions?  Why would it work in Rubular.com but not in my program? What other items should I be looking for? Thanks for your help.

Comment: *It doesn't return the three items that I am looking for.* Please post (as an edit to your question) your updated source code and the result it returns (as far as it is not expected).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about Ruby, but what you describe could be done with:

```
/\b[A-Z-]+(?:\s+[A-Z-]+)+\b/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     (?<=\s)(?:[A-Z\-\s]+)(?=\s|\.|,)
```

This Regex finds all words an caps between blank and other punctuation marks.

Answer (score 0):

In your current regular expressions, it seems you require the resulting all-caps string to be at least 3 characters long. So the quick version would be: `/[A-Z][^a-z]+[A-Z]/` This will allow for punctuation, such as apostrophes and dashes, in the phrases; while avoiding trailing spaces and punctuation.

However, if there's any chance at all you'll need to be matching accented and other international characters, you may want to rewrite it using character classes as: `/[[:upper:]][^[:lower:]]+[[:upper:]]/`, which may just be clearer anyway.